# SWIG: generate additional (hand-rolled) Java class

Tags: swig

I'm using SWIG to generate a Java JNI wrapper for my DLL.

As part of it, I want to generate a custom exception class, but I want to provide the complete Java class implementation for my exception class myself.

I can of course just put my Java class in a separate file, but is it possible to embed such a hand-rolled Java class into a SWIG script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the class is an inner class of some sort you're pretty much left with writing it as a separate file since that's what it needs to be when you come to compile the Java.

I'm slightly puzzled why you would want to write your own pure Java exception class though - the normal thing to do with SWIG would be derive from `std::exception`, even if it's through a `%inline` directive and merge the C++ exception hierarchy with the Java one naturally and for free.

There is a workaround you could use if you really want (although I personally would neverdo it) to generate a pure Java class from the SWIG interface though:

```
%module test

%nodefaultctor MyException;
%typemap(javabody) MyException %{
  // Java stuff goes here (or in javacode typemap)
%}
%typemap(javafinalize) MyException ""
%typemap(javadestruct) MyException ""

struct MyException {};
```

Which generates:

```
public class MyException {
  // stuff goes here

}
```

But since that is clearly an ugly hack I'd strongly recommend avoiding it entirely and just writing the class like normal in your source distribution.